# Query to get all rows grouped by a field value with a condition on another field

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have following query:

```
SELECT 
a.id_posicion,
a.profesional, 
MAX( a.fecha_hora ) AS fechaPosicion, 
a.latitud, 
a.longitud, 
b.tipo_profesional, 
b.nombre, 
b.apellidos,
c.tipo_profesional as tipoProfesional,
b.profile_image,
b.tel as tel, 
e.especialidad as especialidad_profesional,
b.ciudad as ciudad, 
b.departamento as departamento,
b.id_firebase as id_firebase 

FROM tb_ultima_posicion_pro a 

INNER JOIN users b ON b.id = a.profesional 

INNER JOIN tb_profesionales c ON c.id_profesionales = b.tipo_profesional

INNER JOIN tb_especialidades_profesional d ON d.profesional = b.id 

INNER JOIN tb_especialidades e ON d.especialidad = e.id_especialidad  

GROUP BY a.profesional 

ORDER BY fechaPosicion DESC
```

What I need is to get all records from the table tb_ultima_posicion_pro, grouped by the field `profesional`, which means that I get only a row for each profesional (that is ok), and for each profesional I need to get te row with the newest field `fecha_hora`, which is a datetime field.

What I am getting with this query is a row for each profesional (ok) but not the one with the newest `fecha_hora` field value.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: you are using `GROUP BY` in a [invalid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) way ... *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause."*

Comment: you make a select with the same grouping where you get the newest dqata and join them to the same table

Comment: See the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for many solutions to this type of problem. The most straightforward if you use MySQL 8.0 is to use window functions.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I will take a look at your proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, You can first fetch the maximum fetch_hora by grouping the table tb_ultima_posicion_pro and then can join other tables -

```
SELECT a.id_posicion
      ,a.profesional
      ,am.fecha_hora AS fechaPosicion
      ,a.latitud
      ,a.longitud
      ,b.tipo_profesional
      ,b.nombre
      ,b.apellidos
      ,c.tipo_profesional as tipoProfesional
      ,b.profile_image
      ,b.tel as tel
      ,e.especialidad as especialidad_profesional
      ,b.ciudad as ciudad
      ,b.departamento as departamento
      ,b.id_firebase as id_firebase 
FROM tb_ultima_posicion_pro a
INNER JOIN (SELECT profesional
                  ,MAX(fecha_hora) AS fecha_hora
            FROM tb_ultima_posicion_pro 
            GROUP BY profesional) am ON a.profesional = am.profesional
                                    AND a.fecha_hora = am.fecha_hora
INNER JOIN users b ON b.id = a.profesional 
INNER JOIN tb_profesionales c ON c.id_profesionales = b.tipo_profesional
INNER JOIN tb_especialidades_profesional d ON d.profesional = b.id 
INNER JOIN tb_especialidades e ON d.especialidad = e.id_especialidad
ORDER BY fechaPosicion DESC
```

Comment: thank you, but using your proposal I am getting all records, not grouped by profesional

Comment: sorry, I am not getting all records (5807), I am getting 46208 records.

Comment: thank you, now I am getting 5776 records, the number of records should be 7

Comment: It should be 7 only or 5807?

Comment: the query must be grouped by profesional, and there are only 7 different profesional values. The total number of records in the table is 5807

Comment: Please try it now.

Comment: yes, it works now, thank you for your time and effort

Comment: I am not sure who have downvoted the accepted answer.

Comment: I don´t know, I have accepted your answer and upvoted it also. There was a downvote at your first proposal, but not from me.